# How to select columns based on multiple conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a table that has multiple `price-timestamp` tuples:

```
#mytable;
id;<somecolumns>;price1;timestamp1;price2;timestamp2;
```

I want to export each price-timestamp tuple in a temp table, but only the prices whose timestamp is within a specific time interval:

```
#mytemp
id;price1;price2;
```

I could achieve this by repeating the sql for each tuple:

```
INSERT INTO mytemp (price1)
SELECT price1 FROM mytable WHERE timestamp1 > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR;

INSERT INTO mytemp (price2)
SELECT price2 FROM mytable WHERE timestamp2 > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR;

#repeat for all price-timestamp tuples
```

Question: could I optimize this into **one single sql query**?

Comment: Your table `mytemp` still has two columns, `price1` and `price2`. And you want to produce rows where one of the prices is filled and the other is empty? So if a `mytable` row's timestamps both match, you want to split this in two rows? (At least this is what your inserts do.) And what does "#repeat for all price-timestamp tuples" mean? It may help a lot, if you show sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 3):

you can use case when

```
  SELECT
   sum(case when timestamp1 > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR then price1 else 0 end) as price1,
    sum(case when timestamp2 > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR then price2 else 0 end)
    as price2
     FROM mytable  ;
```

but if you want insert just select

```
INSERT INTO mytemp (price1,price2)
SELECT
   sum(case when timestamp1 > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR then price1 else 0 end) as price1,
    sum(case when timestamp2 > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR then price2 else 0 end)
    as price2
     FROM mytable
```

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong. This query will result in insertion of one row but that is not what OP's current queries are doing right?

Answer (score 1):

try this using `case when`

```
INSERT INTO mytemp (price1,price2)
SELECT max(case when timestamp1 > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR then price1 end),max(case when timestamp2 > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR then price2 end) 
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT price1 , '' as price2 from testa WHERE timestamp1 > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR
UNION
SELECT '' as price1, price2  as price from testa WHERE timestamp2 > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR
```

Comment: `price2` is missing in the results for this.

Comment: Don't use double quotes for string literals. Use single quotes as defined in the SQL standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross join` to unpivot the data:

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then price1
             when n.n = 2 then price2
        end),
       (case when n.n = 1 then timestamp1
             when n.n = 2 then timestamp2
        end)       
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
having timestamp > now() - interval 3 hour;
```

However, your method or the equivalent with `union all` is likely to be the fastest method if you have an index on `timestamp`.